# How to skip the SQL(part of the SQL) parsing in antlr4?

Tags: sql, parsing, antlr4

Sorry for this question was closed and can not be reopened, and my poor english, it was translated by website indeed. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035964/how-to-skip-sql-parsing-in-antlr4

@BartKiers Thanks for being interested in this question, let me give it a detailed example.

There are lots of SQL queries, such as `select * from user` or `update user set field1 = 'value1' where condition = 'value'` etc, let's called it original SQL queries.

There is a java program which intercepts and parses all the original SQL queries into Parse Tree nodes by ANTLR4, and then rewrites the query (which depended on the parse phase) by the java program, so the original SQL queries may be parsed and rewritten as

```
select field1, field1_encrypted, field1_digest, field2 from user
```

or

```
update user 
  set field1 = value1, 
      field1_encrypted = encrypt_algorithm(value1), 
      field1_digest = digest_algorithm(value1) 
  where condition_digest = digest_algorithm(values)
```

etc.

While they finished the rewritten phase, they should be executed as SQLStatement, the SELECT was executed as SelectSQLStatement while UPDATE executed as UpdateSQLStatement.

Now I thought some of the original SQL queries should skip the parse phase, and the rewrite phase which should be skipped as the same, but the originalSQL queries should be executed as it was.

I thought to mark those with comment as

```
/* PARSE_PHASE_SKIPPED=TRUE */ originalSQL
```

or prefix `SKIP` as

```
SKIP originalSQL
```

, I wish to parse the whole marked but original SQL query part into Parse Tree nodes by ANTLR4, and executed it as ParsePhaseSkippedSQLStatement.

Can ANTLR4 support on this situation, and how should the grammar be written? Thanks in advance.

====================

Thank you for your reply @Mike Cargal, Yes, almost.

Let me say it again and give a more detailed example.

There is a java system that we call it X, X has lots of SQL queries that the developers write and guarantee that those SQLs can be executed correctly by Ibatis / JPA etc, let's named those SQL queries as original SQL queries.

Using below original SQL queries as examples:

```
insert into user (username, id_no) values ('xyz', '123456')
```

```
select username, id_no from user u where u.id_no = '123456'
```

We say the column id_no on table user is sensitive data, we should save ciphertext instead of plaintext, so the originalSQLs would be parsed by ANTLR and rewritten by java code as below, let's named those SQLs as rewritten SQL queries, also rewritten SQL queries should be executed correctly by Ibatis / JPA etc.

```
insert 
  into user (username, id_no, id_no_cipher, id_no_digest) 
  values ('xyz', '', 'encrypted_123456', 'digest_123456')
```

```
select username, id_no_cipher as id_no 
  from user u 
  where u.id_no_digest = 'digest_123456'
```

In this case:

1、we see that the rewrite phase depends on the parse phase, original SQL queries need to be correctly parsed then to be rewritten by java code.

2、all original SQL queries are parsed but only a few matching the sensitive rules are rewritten to rewritten SQL queries.

But there are lots original SQL queries we clearly know that do not need to be rewritten, and also no need to be parsed, and may report exceptions in various complex situations while parsing it, but it should be executed correctly by Ibatis / JPA etc.

So I planed to use sql comment / customized keyword annotation to "turn off" parse phase of it.

Comment: This is still pretty difficult to understand, but I wouldn't want to be on the receiving end of me asking a question in another language, so I sympathize.  I *think* I see what you're trying to do, and have provided some an answer that may set you in the right direction.   Simply put, it's not an ANTLR thing, but there are ways you could use ANTLR in being able to solve your problem.

Comment: The standard way to *switch on/off* SQL statements is to start the WHERE clause using `WHERE 1=1` or `WHERE True` , and adding the other conditions with `AND col1= 'val1'` BTW: `/*` is a non- standard comment in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to use some sort of comment/annotation to "turn off" execution of the following SQL statement.

(NOTE: You can't really skip "parsing" part of the input.  This will address ways in which you could skip *processing* part of the parsed input, which I believe is what you're ultimately wanting to accomplish.)

This would not be an ANTLR concern.  ANTLR's responsibility is to parse you input stream and produce a parse tree (not technically an AST) that correctly represents the structure of your input.

Executing the SQL is not what ANTLR does.  It does, however, generate utility Listener and Visitor classes that can be used to cleanly and efficiently navigate the resulting parse tree.  There can be a lot of code involved in actually executing the SQL from the parse tree.  Often, the first step is to produce an AST from the parse tree to make it easier to deal with.

You have a couple of alternatives (as you hint at).

1 - Using the current grammar an putting these annotations inside of comments (`/* PARSE_PHASE_SKIPPED=TRUE */`)

This *can* be done, but it's a bit "messy".  It's most likely that `COMMENT` tokens are `-> skip`ed (or perhaps sent to `-> channel(HIDDEN)`).  This makes it MUCH easier to write the parser rules as you don't have to include optional `COMMENT`s everywhere a comment could appear.  That said, if you send `COMMENT` tokens to the `HIDDEN` channel, they are still in the token stream even though they are ignored by the parser.  The `COMMENT` tokens won't be in the rule Context objects that the listeners/visitors deal with, but you could look backwards/forwards in the token stream for `COMMENT` nodes.

2 - you could introduce some new syntax for annotations (similar to your `SKIP` idea).  To do this you'll have to extend the syntax in the grammar to recognize these annotations.  They'd have to be distinguishable from valid SQL, so a simple `SKIP` is probably not going to work.

The benefit of this approach is that, when you extend the grammar to recognize annotations, you can be very specific about where annotations are allowed.  You'd be able to include them in your parse tree, making them easier to locate.

With either of these approaches, you would use a visitor or listener to go through your parse tree looking for the comment/annotation and then mark the subsequent statement with an indicator that you don't want to execute it.  (You might use the information to simply skip the parse tree to AST transformation of the "skipped" nodes).

Comment: Yes, almost, Since SKIP is reserved by ANTLR, here using SKIPD. Could you show me an example to use customized keyword annotation SKIPD to implement it on mysql? I try it but got can not recognize SKIPD exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand your question correctly. In your environment you run SQL queries (not "SQLs", btw.), which may contain data that must not reach the server as is. It doesn't matter if that is sensitive data or what else. All what matters is that you want to replace the text in the queries.

For that you parse the queries and rewrite them, before sending them to the server. However, you don't want to do that for all queries, but only for specific ones. And you came up with the idea to mark queries (or query parts) that must not be transformed, with a special comment. Does this match your intention so far?

Now I wonder why you want to accomplish that on query (parsing) level. It's not the parsing you want to modify but the semantic handling of the parse result (here the parse tree, as Mike Cargal already mentioned). So, in my opinion you don't need to introduce special markup for your queries, but instead define criterions that indicate which data must be replaced.

When you think about that you will probably realise that data for specific fields (columns) in specific tables need to be replaced. You can actually keep a list of schema/table/columns tuples, which tell your rewriter if a value must be rewritten. Everything else stays as it is.

ANTLR4 has nothing to do in this process. It's all to be done in the semantic phase (the processing of the parse tree using a parse tree listener). In this phase you have to collect all column references that are used in a query. Then you compare that list with the list for the rewriter. If a column reference matches, the rewriter has to rewrite the text for it in the query.

That task is however non-trivial, because of nested queries (subqueries, where inner queries can reference tables from an outer query). This is btw. pretty similar to the way code completion works, where you have to provide a possible column list for all mentioned tables in a query. That's why I have written (C++) code [to collect such references](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/code-completion/mysql-code-completion.cpp#L315) in MySQL Workbench's SQL code completion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes, a perfect match. I don't want to do that for all queries, but only for specific ones, and I'd like to explain why I thinking of do that on query (parsing) level.
I am already write lots of ANTLR4 grammars, visitors and listeners to parse DDL & DML etc into SQLStatements, but in various complex scenarios and situations (such as sql functions etc), parse exception would be occurred , and I can't cover it all, my test colleagues cannot cover all the parsed testcases either. So I am looking forward to find some way to SKIP the parse phase.

Comment: I am thinking of parsing queries like `SKIPD sql` into SkipdSQLStatement but do not parse the `sql` part, yes, the `sql` part as the whole plain string. I don't know if this will work and how?